# FancyBox with video on iPad-video plays but is black???-(doesn't appear)

Tags: ipad, video, fancybox

Solved the fancybox doubleclick issue
solved the Fancybox scrolllbar issue(Firefox only)

1 remaining issue that has me pulling my hair.

Everything works and plays fine on the desktop across browsers.

But, on my ipad, when I popup the video, it seems to play(I see the loading and playback indicators)
but NO VIDEO!

```
http:///.bitstream/ca/beta
```

As a check, if I link to the video directly

```
http://www.bitstream.ca/beat/video1.html
```

It plays fine.

WTF?

Answer (score -1):

I think I solved
not sure why but adding

```
autoSize: false,
```

seems to do the trick. Video now shows and plays fine on ipad.

Not sure why someone down voted this? It seems to be a valid issue.